# Filling an area below a curve with a colormap defined by the function of the curve

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure, area

Consider the following plot:

[image]

On the left you can see the fill of a circle with respect to a profile of a function using `patch` command

```
t = linspace(-pi,pi,100);
c = exp(-cos(t));
figure(1)
patch(cos(t),sin(t),c)
axis equal
```

On the right you see the profile of the function along the dashed line axis on the left, which is filled using the `area` command.

```
figure(2)
area(cos(t),c,0);
```

what I'm trying to do is fill the area below the curve (right panel) with the colors defined by the colormap of the representation in the left panel. The results should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could come up with is this:

```matlab
function q55322965
% Evaluate the equation (half domain!)
t = linspace(-pi,0,50);
c = exp(-cos(t));

% Turn vectors into a mesh:
[TT,CC] = meshgrid(cos(t),c);

% Clear all points that are above the curve:
CC(CC > c) = NaN;

% Fill in the rectangle between the chart and zero:
CC(end+1,:) = 0;
TT(end+1,:) = TT(end,:);

% Plot:
figure(); mesh(TT,CC,CC,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','interp'); view([0,90]);
```

Which yields:

[image]

If you want a less jagged look when plotting with this method, you can increase the resolution in `t`. For example, if we use `500` instead of `50` in the `linspace` we get:

[image]

Comment: why did you choose only half of the domain and not the full range [-pi,pi]?